# $.each Doesn't work for object array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

i have a array and i need to use each of this items , but forEach and $.each dont work for array here a exmple ( [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnsadeghy/4HJ4B/) )

```
var person = new Array();
person["firstName"] = "John";
person["lastName"] = "Doe";
person["age"] = 46;
jQuery.each(person, function(index, item) {
    alert(index + " : " + item);
});
```

Comment: I recommend to read the MDN JavaScript guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an associative array, which is really just an object. To enumerate the key-value pairs of some object `obj`, use a for-loop:

```
for (let key in obj) {
    console.log(key, ":", obj[key])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not an object array; it's an array to which you've added string-named properties. JavaScript is not like PHP - there's a distinct difference between arrays and plain objects.

The `$.each()` function will detect that you've passed it an array instance, and it will then *only* look at the numerically-indexed properties. Your string-named properties will be ignored.

Declare your "person" object as a plain object and things will work better:

```
var person = {};
```

JavaScript arrays are for numerically-indexed properties. If you want something that maps strings to values, use a plain object.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `forEach` or `$.each()` to loop over an array they loop over the *numeric* indices. Of which you don't have any given that your code is creating properties with string property names. Use an object instead of an array:

```
var person = {};
// other code as is
```

You will then be able to use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), because it can handle arrays or plain objects. You *won't* be able to use the [array `forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) because you won't then have an array.

Also your fiddle doesn't work because you didn't include jQuery under the *Frameworks & Extensions* section at the left. See this updated, working version: http://jsfiddle.net/4HJ4B/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var jsonStr = '[{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "age": 46},{"firstName": "John-2", "lastName": "Doe-2", "age": 26}]';
var person = $.parseJSON(jsonStr);
$(person).each(function(index, item) {
    console.log(index + " : " + item.firstName);
});
```